# Missing tlmgr texlive 2012

Tags: texlive

I just succesfully installed texlive 2012, apart from the fact that
tlmgr is missing: it should be in the directory 
/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux/  but there's not! The
only thing with the name tlmgr is a link to a perl script!
How could I solve the problem?
I'm running Ubuntu, if it can help!

Thank you for the answers!

Comment: That's exactly how it should be. Have you tried calling `tlmgr --gui`?

Comment: Welcome to tex exchange! There's quite a lot of detail in this answer: [how do i update my distribution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55459/6621)

Answer (score 4):

tlmgr *is* a perl script.

`tlmgr update --all` doesn't work, because it needs root access to apply any changes

`sudo tlmgr update --all` doesn't work, because the path probably isn't part of root's $PATH.

You can run this:
`sudo /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux/tlmgr update --all`

Comment: Or `sudo -i` followed by `tlmgr update --all`.